# how to disable or hide google form field from url

Tags: forms, google-forms

I am trying to disable the field in google form via url. I tried various ways to diable from url but its not happening.

```
entry.496232457=disabled
```

above code snippet only change the values and does not disable the field . Is there any way to hide or disable the form field?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to neither disable nor hide a question directly.

Alternatively, you can conditionally show questions with a 'condition' question:

[Show questions based on answers](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/141062?hl=en)

1. create a checkbox / dropdown question which act as the condition
2. move the question you want to display conditionally to a new section
3. set `Go to section based on answer` of each choice respectively
4. pass the 'condition' to the url